# C# Try-Catch & Exception handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, try-catch

In various parts of code in a current project, there is constant usage of

```
try
{
    //code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //display nicely formatted error message
}
```

My question is, under the assumption that the code handles all known/assumed errors (such as checking if objects are null etc), should a try-catch be placed around the code that displays errors in a application-global format?

Or is it better practice to let the error throw an exception and have the application crash naturally?

Thanks

Comment: Application should never "crash naturally". Even though your car has a bumper - I advice you to use brakes instead.

Comment: I agree with @zerkms, an application should never crash naturally... check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173160(v=vs.100).aspx) basic documentaion on C# exception handling....

Comment: are you developing a logging module that should not crash naturally ?

Comment: This has been covered endlessly on StackOverflow in the past, you should have done a search before posting your question. Rule of thumb: *only catch an exception if you are going to action it right there or add value to it (i.e. transform it).* I'll see if I can dig out one of the reasonable previous questions on this.

Answer (score 6):

Catching all exceptions like this is *not* a good practice, except at the top level of your application, where you display a nice error message. Done right, it could preserve end user's perception of your program as *slightly* buggy, but reasonable overall. In contrast, letting your application crash is the easiest way to convince your end users that your application is bad beyond repair.

As far as exception prevention goes, there are two major kinds of exceptions - programming errors (null pointer, class cast, out of range, etc.) and environment errors (file not found, network path is unavailable, user entry error, etc.) You can and should avoid the first kind, and be prepared to handle the second kind.

Comment: In some contexts the line between those kinds of exceptions may be fuzzy, especially when reading files from disk. If application Fnord is asked to open a file which starts with a header containing a Fnord-specific GUID, and won't be able do anything useful with the file if it doesn't meet certain criteria, code which assumes the file will meet the criteria may be much more readable than code which validates every aspect of the file that might cause an exception to be thrown if it were invalid.

Answer (score 3):

```
class PerformTask
{
    public void ConnectToDB(requiredParams)
    {


    }
}

class PerformTaskConsumer
{
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      try
      {
         PerformTask obj = new PerformTask();
      }

      catch(RelaventExceptions)
      {

      }
   } 


}
```

Just avoid the exception if you can. If Exception occurs, leave it to the caller what he wants to do with the Exception. The caller may decide to show a well formatted message about the exception or decide to crash or what ever.

Eric Lippert has a good article regarding exceptions. [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct schools of thought here and proponents of both are often shocked and amazed that anyone could possibly believe the other way. In the end, it's a matter of preference and what your target user base is expecting and/or willing to accept, and more importantly, how well you know what your application does. (Your question implies that you didn't write all of the code involved, so that last bit might be trickier than you think.)

First of, I assume you are talking about an end-user application here, and not a class library. There is almost never a good reason to catch exceptions in a class library that you're not explicitly handling. You always leave that decision up to the callers.

In an end-user application, however, the decision is ultimately yours, as there isn't anyone higher up the call chain. In this case, you have two broad options:

#### Fail Fast

Some people believe that you are better off letting your application crash as soon as physically possible, when an error is encountered. While it seems a bit counter productive, keep in mind what it means to run into an unhandled exception: you literally *have no idea* what went wrong; even something as simple as your error logging code could behave in a way you aren't expecting.

If you are handling exceptions properly at the call sites, you should only receive this kind of 'unexpected' error when something really, really bad happens: out of memory, corrupted stacks, etc. The kind of thing you can't really recover from, no matter what, so there's no point in trying.

#### Fail Gracefully

Other people believe that you should try to isolate errors whenever possible, to keep your users from losing information. If your application is modular enough, its possible that a total failure in one area could have no effect at all on data in another area.

This is a riskier proposition: you have to be very careful not to leave yourself in an inconsistent state. It requires that you know, for sure, that nothing in the failing code is changing state from some other part of the code.

#### In Conclusion

As usual, the "right" answer is probably somewhere in the middle. In general, the risk of running in an inconsistent state is almost always a good reason to allow the application to die. Of course, you'll probably still want to do some level of logging here, which you can accomplish in a couple of ways. My preference is not to use exceptions for this, but to hook into the various "unhandled exception" events at the top level like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx), or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx). Log your exceptions in those event handlers, maybe display a "friendlier" error dialog, then let your application shut down. For example, we put something similar to this in the WPF applications we produce:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             DispatcherUnhandledException="UnhandledException">


private void UnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    logger.FatalException("OH NOES! Bad stuff happened, bailing out.", e.Exception);
    MessageBox.Show("holy cow something bad happened:\r\n" + e.Exception.Message);
}
```

However, there are places where catching *all* exceptions might be safe; this is mostly limited to places where all of the data is going to be discarded no matter what. For example, printing or exporting the results of an already-completed operation might fail "safely", with no ill effects to the rest of the application. You probably wouldn't want your application to crash just because the user doesn't have a printer. (I have even run into cases with one third-party printing library where it explicitly threw `System.Exception` on error...) But you have to be very careful that you know what you're doing, and that your data is truly isolated from the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0):

A tip to you to know where to put the try ... catch block.

Put a global exception handler, to catch all exception not handled. Log the stack trace and exception, display a apologize to end user and CLOSE THE PROGRAM (never try to continue here).

Let the application run, when it crashes, check the reason and correct handle the exception with the most specific exception possible.

**Remember:** *Exception are for exception, not for normal program behavior.*